# Weights and biases in tf.layers module in TensorFlow 1.0

Tags: tensorflow

How do you access the weights and biases when using tf.layers module in TensorFlow 1.0? The advantage of tf.layers module is that you don't have to separately create the variables when making a fully connected layer or convolution layer.

I couldn't not find anything in the documentation regarding accessing them or adding them in summaries after they are created.

Comment: If you need access to the weights (tf calls them "kernels") & biases after you've initialized your layer, I would argue that tf.layers is not the right level of abstraction for you. Are you only trying to get them into a summary or are you doing other stuff with the weights & biases?

Comment: I am only trying to get them on a summary, and visualize the weight distribution on Tensorboard. I don't need to manipulate the weights directly during trainin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `tf.layers` (i.e. TF core) support summaries yet. Rather you have to use what's in contrib ...knowing that stuff in contrib, may eventually move into core but that the current API may change:

> The layers module defines convenience functions summarize_variables,
>   summarize_weights and summarize_biases, which set the collection
>   argument of summarize_collection to VARIABLES, WEIGHTS and BIASES,
>   respectively.

Checkout:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers#Summaries
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/131c3a67a7b8d27fd918e0bc5bddb3cb086de57e/tensorflow/python/layers/layers.py